# Pending Request | NestJS WebSocket Observer

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, observable, nestjs

I'm developing NestJS app which asks Binance Websocket API for some data. I got all data in my console.log but in Postman or Browser Window a request is pending. I can't understand what's wrong. How can I get data in Postman or Browser Window? Please help.

**Update**

I developed a new WebSocket server that sends data from Binance's WS to UI. And on the UI side I got only the first item :| What's wrong?

**Coin.gateway.ts**

```
import { MessageBody, SubscribeMessage, WebSocketGateway, WebSocketServer } from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import { from, of, take, map, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Coin } from './classes/coin';
import * as coinlist from './list/coins.json'


@WebSocketGateway(811, {transports: ['websocket', 'polling'], cors: true})
export class CoinGateway {

  @WebSocketServer()
  server: Server;

  @SubscribeMessage('events')
  handleMessage(@MessageBody() data: any) {
    console.log('data',data)
    const coins = new Coin(coinlist, 'usdt', 'miniTicker')
    return coins.getCryptoData().pipe(map((c) => {
      return c
    }))
  }
}
```

**Coin.ts**

```
import { GetCryptocurrencies } from "./abstract/get-cryptocurrencies";
import { WebSocket } from "ws";
import { Logger } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

export class Coin extends GetCryptocurrencies {
    private readonly logger = new Logger(Coin.name)
    private baseUrl: string
    private url: string
    constructor(coin: { name: string, symbol: string }[], pair: string, method: string) {
        super(coin, pair, method)
        this.baseUrl = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams='
        this.url = coin.map((c) => {
            return `${c.symbol.toLowerCase()}${pair}@${method}`
        }).join('/')
        }

    getCryptoData(): any {
        const stream$ = new Observable((observer) => {

            const ws = new WebSocket(`${this.baseUrl}${this.url}`)
            ws.on('open', () => {
                this.logger.log('Connection established')
            })
            ws.onmessage = (msg: any) => {
                const message = JSON.parse(msg.data)
                observer.next(message)
            }
            ws.on('close', () => {
                this.logger.log('Connection closed')
            })
        })
        return stream$
    }
}
```

**Client UI useEffect hook**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io('ws://localhost:811', {transports: ['websocket']})
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('Connection established from client')

        socket.emit('events', '', (res: any) => {
            console.log(res)
        })
        const engine = socket.io.engine;
        console.log(engine.transport.name); // in most cases, prints "polling"

        engine.once("upgrade", () => {
            // called when the transport is upgraded (i.e. from HTTP long-polling to WebSocket)
            console.log(engine.transport.name); // in most cases, prints "websocket"
        });

        engine.on("packetCreate", ({ type, data }) => {
            // called for each packet sent
            console.log('Stype', type)
            console.log('Sdata', data)
        });

    })
    }, [])
```

Comment: Solved problem in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70049397/why-i-got-only-first-item-nestjs-websocket-socket-io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening because you're keeping the Observable (and implicitly the underneath WebSocket) alive, which means that the HTTP GET call never completes.

You could solve it by making sure that the Observable completes after the first data comes from the WS channel. So add `take(1)` inside the pipe, like this:

```js
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

......................................

@Injectable()
export class GetDataService {
    getCoins(): Observable<any[]> {
        const coins = new Coin(coinlist, 'usdt', 'miniTicker')
        return coins.getCryptoData().pipe(
        take(1), // <---- I've added this
        map((c) => {
            console.log(c)
            return c
        }))
    }
}
```

It should fix your issue.

Comment: But now I got only the first item in Browser window and in the console.log also

Comment: Yep, which is pretty much expected with `take(1)`. The thing is that what you're trying to achieve is opening a WS connection between Server and UI, by making a HTTP call. Which is not correct, assuming that you'll have a lot of users. And keeping a HTTP request opened for for an undefined period is also not ideal.

Comment: What you should do instead, is to have a WS client on the UI side as well, which listens to a WS connection on the Server. And then the HTTP GET call (actually it would be a POST ideally), would just make the Server to get the WS data from Binance and send it further to the UI (via the other WS channel). Something like that could work.

Comment: Hello again, I developed the front side and now I got the only first item. Can you please check my origin post? I edited it.